# $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a convergent sequence and $a_n \in [0,1]$ for all $n$. Proof of limit $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ lies in [0,1].

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Textbook question:

> $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a convergent sequence and $a_n \in [0,1]$ for all $n$. Proof of limit $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ lies in [0,1].

I don't understand the question I suppose. It would seem that it answers itself...? If $a_n \in [0,1]$ for all $n$, then of course the limit does since we know it is convergent...?

What am I missing?

Comment: Something to think about: if the closed brackets were replaced by open brackets, would the statement still be true?

Comment: What do you know about closed sets and cluster points?

Comment: @rlartiga essentially nothing comes to mind. I know monotone sequences, squeeze theorem, inf and sup

Comment: Taking the example of  @anaconda what happen if you take $a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$ which lives in the set $(0,1)$ what happen with the limit value?

Comment: @rlartiga We get 0 by L'hop?

Comment: Yes is $0$ but it don't lives in the set $(0,1)$

Comment: @rlartiga True, but I am obviously missing something, I can't see how this solves my problem unfortunately

I am going to sleep, It will probably make sense in the morning.

Comment: The point is that when you consider an open interval like $(0,1)$ from the upper example, the statement doesnt hold any more for all converging sequences...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the limit of $a_n$ don't live in $[0,1]$. Without loss of generality assume that limit $L$ is $L<0$ (i.e. is at the left of the interval). Convergence says $\forall \epsilon>0 \exists N, \forall n>N |a_n-L|<\epsilon $. Take $\epsilon=|\frac{L}{2}|=-\frac{L}{2}$ then in the interval $\left(\frac{3L}{2},\frac{L}{2}\right)$ (which is not in the interval $[0,1]$) we must find all the elements of $a_n$ from $n\geq N$, then is a contradiction because all the elements of $a_n$ lives in $[0,1]$